# Delete In Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application for video upload and play.The administrator can upload and users can view the uploaded files.I am automatically populating links from database to a repeater.My target is the administrator can delete the uploaded file.The file also delete from the database.I am using SQl experess and VS2005 .How can i do this?

Comment: This question is broad in scope and sounds like a you want others to do your work for you. You haven't even told us what it is supposed to be written in!

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little vague but it sounds like you're wanting information on data access and ASP.NET databound controls. I would recommend reading all of the articles found on http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/.